# Selenium Webdriver: Highligh an Element at some Coordinates

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

I am automating an application which is built with HTML5 using Selenium Webdriver. Now I want to highlight the point I have clicked. Highlighting the element is not a big deal but to know at what coordinates it has been clicked is what I need. For ex. I am clicking an Canvas element at coordinates 200,500.

If I implement java script to highlight element then it will highlight whole Canvas element where as I want to highlight the point(200,500) clicked. Please provide your answers. Thanks in advance.

I am using specflow with C#.

Code for clicking the Canvas at coordinates:

```
public void ClickCanvasElement(IWebDriver driver, By locator, int offsetX, int offsetY)
        {
            try
            {
                IWebElement element = FindElement(driver, locator);
                Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    if ((element.Displayed == true && element.Enabled == true) || element == null)
                    {
                        actions.MoveToElement(element, offsetX, offsetY).Click().Perform();
                        break;
                    }
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we could help you. I have a colleague who is trying to achieve the same thing so he might help.

Comment: Your question conflicts with the title. One states highlight an element and the other states know what coordinates were clicked. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Title and the description are pointing to the same thing, I just want to know the coordinates clicked by highlighting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:- You need to use javascript to highlight particular element.

```
 public void ClickCanvasElement(IWebDriver driver, By locator, int offsetX, int offsetY)
            {
                try
                {
                    IWebElement element = FindElement(driver, locator);
                    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        if ((element.Displayed == true && element.Enabled == true) || element == null)
                        {
                            actions.MoveToElement(element, offsetX, offsetY).Click().Perform();


    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);"element","color: red; border: 3px solid red;");

                            break;
                        }
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution what comes to my mind is to edit canvas itself, for example drawing a square/circle with x,y parameters(200,500) as first two arguments in context.fillRect. You could try this approach:

```
 IWebElement element = FindElement(driver, locator);
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

 js.ExecuteScript("var example = arguments[0]
                   var context = example.getContext('2d')
                   context.fillRect(200,500,10,10)",element);
```

However It will only works If provided by You coordinates are canvas coordinate. If not You will need to take more complicated path (Hope will help: http://javascript.info/coordinates)

1. Find canvas element
2. Extract absolute coords of founded element
3. Calculate relative coordinations
4. Use javascript for creating new shape on Canvas from point 1